# DSC Random Built in Error

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

I randomly get this error logged in the DSC Operational log when running DSC configurations. I have no idea what it means or why it's occurring. Please note this is a built in DSC resource and file mentioned.

What's going on here?

> Error Message: PowerShell Desired State Configuration failed to
>   register MOF filePSDesiredStateConfiguration using Mofcomp.exe during
>   discovery of
>   C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DscResources\MSFT_ScriptResource\MSFT_ScriptResource.schema.mof
>   resource . Check the MOF file and try again.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting it but I can explain what it means. In order to interact effectively with WMI/WINRM, DSC registers the resource MOF file with WMI. Mofcomp.exe is the tool, that ships in windows, used to compile a MOF file and register with WMI. This error indicates that for some reason DSC wasn't able to register script resource mof file with WMI.

Comment: ensure you are running powershell as an administrator